# RESTful way to do degradable Multiple Models in a Form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rest

So far, I've not been able to find a solution that is able to allow a form to interact with two models that have a one-to-many relationship. Say for example, a customer has many items.

Currently, I've implemented solutions using Javascript that enables users to add/remove rows to the item list. Let's keep it simple, we're creating new records here.

In improving this to be degradable, I've instead created a 'Add Item' button that commits a different value, so that in my create action, I'm able to capture the new attributes and  add a new Item to the customer object.

However, since item is new and has no id, I have no way of removing a particular item. I've thought of using indexes and added post buttons/links to remove, but this sort of makes everything messy and I can't use my partial for collections. So I feel like it's a hack; is there a better alternative?

Comment: I've struggled with this myself, so I'm interested to see if anyone has a solution. It looks like things might get better in future versions (see http://tr.im/99v7), but nested model forms is a weak point of Rails' as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: That looks like what we'll be needing! Good find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use accepts_nested_attributes_for. The Railscasts episode henrikloevborg mentions covers a method of doing this kind of thing that's been obsoleted by accepts_nested_attributes_for.

You can do it without accepts_nested_attributes_for. Which might be necessary if you don't want to upgrade to Rails 2.3.

In your javascript to remove an item, you should add a hidden field to the form called _delete with the value of true. Then in your controller. Ignore any new records with the _delete field, and destroy any existing ones.

All that's built in to accept_nested_attributes_for

Play around with the code in the [complex-forms-exmample](http://github.com/alloy/complex-form-examples) github repository. It's essentially the code from Railscast #75 updated to use the newer feature, accepts_nested_attributes_for.

You will notice that it doesn't use RJS to accomplish the dynamic addition/removal of records. Also compared to what you've been doing it creates on submit, not during a remote call. The automatic addition/deletion of items is handled using content_for tags to create a template stored in a javascript function and the Prototype library to modify a hidden field, which accepts_nested_attributes_for uses to destroy objects you want to remove.

Comment: Yes, I know that the new features definitely make this possible. I guess I have to mark you as the correct answer anyways =)

Comment: The javascript contained in the complex-forms-example is a bit of a hack, but doesn't feel that way with all the helper methods to stream line it.